# How i can change my text HTML element when its inside the fetch API?

Tags: javascript

i connect with weather API and i want to change my main.innerText to the weather main for example: Clouds
so when i make it nothing change in my site and i don't know how to solve it

```
    const options = {
     method: "GET",
     headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "beb6daec47msh27687ff8b153d6dp18f96djsnfe889c799384",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "open-weather13.p.rapidapi.com",
    },
   };

    const CityInput = document.getElementById("input");
    const btn = document.getElementById("search");
    const Cityname = document.getElementById("cityname");

    const main = document.getElementById("main");
    const Temp = document.getElementById("Temp");

    btn.addEventListener("click", Citytemp);

    function Citytemp() {
     fetch(
     "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?    q=london&appid=a8e71c9932b20c4ceb0aed183e6a83bb&units=imperial",
    options
     )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      main.innerText = json.main.temp;
    });
  Cityname.innerHTML = CityInput.value;
    }
`

should h4 element change to the main : clouds (json.weather[0].main)
```

Comment: Be careful with sharing you API keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Catch` block to see what's going wrong with API request. However in this case, you don't need to pass headers.

```js
const options = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "beb6daec47msh27687ff8b153d6dp18f96djsnfe889c799384",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "open-weather13.p.rapidapi.com",
  },
};

const btn = document.getElementById("search");
const main = document.getElementById("main");

btn.addEventListener("click", Citytemp);

function Citytemp() {
  fetch(
      "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid=a8e71c9932b20c4ceb0aed183e6a83bb&units=imperial"
    )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      main.innerText = json.main.temp;
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
}
```

```html
<h1 id='main'>Click below to update</h1>
<button id='search'>Click</button>
```